# Invalid connection string - process.env

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to use process.env

-this is db.js-

```
import * as dotenv from "dotenv";
import mongoose from "mongoose";

dotenv.config();

const { DB_URL } = process.env.PRODUCTION ? process.env : "localhost:27017/save-idiot"; 
const { DB_PROTOCOL } =process.env.PRODUCTION ? process.env : "mongodb"

mongoose.connect(`${DB_PROTOCOL}://${DB_URL}`, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useFindAndModify: false,
  useUnifiedTopology: true
});

const db = mongoose.connection;

const handleOpen = () => console.log("✅ Connected to DB");

const handleError = error => console.log(`❌ Error on DB Connection:${error}`);

db.once("open", handleOpen);
db.on("error", handleError);
```

-package.json-

```
"scripts": {
    "dev:server": "nodemon --exec babel-node src/init.js -- delay 2",
    "dev:assets": "cd src && WEBPACK_ENV=development webpack -w",
    "lint": "eslint src/",
    "fix": "eslint --fix src/",
    "clean": "rm -rf build",
    "build:server": "babel src --out-dir build --ignore 'src/assets','src/static','src/webpack.config.js'",
    "build:assets": "cd src && WEBPACK_ENV=production webpack",
    "copy:static": "cp -R src/static src/views build/",
    "build": "npm run clean && npm run lint && npm run build:server && npm run build:assets && npm run copy:static",
    "start": "PRODUCTION=true forever start build/init.js"
  }
```

```
const { DB_URL } = process.env.PRODUCTION ? process.env : "localhost:27017/save-idiot"; 
const { DB_PROTOCOL } =process.env.PRODUCTION ? process.env : "mongodb"
```

if I npm run dev:server,
I want to get "localhost:27017/save-idiot" & "mongodb"

and if I npm start,
I want to get process.env

How can I do this?

Comment: you can add more npm scripts for dev. Where is the error?

Answer (score 0):

You could use  `cross-env` package, it is used to set environment variables.
Once you've installed it, you could try like this:
`"start": "cross-env PRODUCTION=true forever start build/init.js"`

Answer (score 0):

Try use

```
dotenv.config({ path: '.env' });
```

For configure many environments you can use [envdist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/envdist)